# Can optical flow be applied on IR(Infrared thermal) images that have large time gap?

Tags: image-processing

Traditionally optical flow is applied to continuous image sequences. But I wonder if two image particularly thermal image that have bigger timegap (let's say 60 seconds) can perform optical flow to yield, for example, temperature flow direction of a still object? Or is there a better method than optical flow in such situation?

Comment: The announced delay (60 seconds) is meaningless if we know nothing about the propagation time.

Comment: @YvesDaoust what do you mean by propagation time?  I am not familiar with this term. I have a thermal camera that capture thermal frame at about 1/60 fps, I want to know if optical flow or other method can be used to analyze temperature flow between neighbouring frames.

Comment: You said 60 seconds between frames !?

Comment: Don't you want to see heat propagation ?

Comment: yeah, image taken once about every minute. They are used in industrial scenario (casting). The production cycle is about 2 minutes during which I can't take thermal image.